# DRY: minimizing code

Tags: ruby, json, hash

I want a method to create the following json string in many places:

```
{"daily_calendar":{"search":{"print_date":"2014-06-30"}}}
```

I have following four lines of code to make the hash:

```
custom_params, print_date, search = Hash.new, Hash.new, Hash.new
print_date['print_date'] =  @week_day
search['search'] = print_date
custom_params['daily_calendar'] = search
puts custom_params.to_json
```

What is the best way to do it in one or two lines and use it anywhere in the controller?

Comment: What's the rush in selecting an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write as it is:

```
hash = {daily_calendar: {search: {print_date:@week_day} } }
puts hash.to_json
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use hash literals:

```
custom_params = {
    "daily_calendar" => {
        "search" => {
            "print_date" => @week_day
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{daily_calendar: {search: {print_date: @week_day}}}.to_json
```

Answer (score 1):

A recursive expression allows you to have any number of nested hashes:

```
def doit(*h,v)
  h.size == 1 ? { h.first => v } : { h.shift => doit(*h,v) }
end

h = %w[one_more_level daily_calendar search print_date]
doit(*h, 'tue')     
  #=> {"one_more_level"=>{"daily_calendar"=>{"search"=>{"print_date"=>"tue"}}}}
```